# Best way to place images on a over a backgroung image

Tags: website-design, image

I am trying to place an image over an area I already applied bg-image to. The image on top looks and feel overpowering, it also make the page a little bit empty due to the change in contrast.

If I must have the second image over the first, how can this be done so that it complements each other and not totally dominating.[image: nosecond image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make an image less dominating is for it to only have two colors. Eshops use this method on company logos - they remove the color and every logo contains only black and white (or another color instead of black depending on the theme).

[image: look at the brand panel - does it take away your attention from other elements on the page?]

**look at the brand panel in the middle - does it take away your attention from other elements on the page?**

You could also try selectively removing strong colors but that may end up messing the image.